# clicking an 'input' in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, button, input, click

```
<input class="jss1805" name="confirmWeight" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="">
```

The code^ is from a html website and its a checkbox which I want to click. Except it's an input rather than a button or td. Am I able to click this as when I run selenium it seems to not find it.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/form/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/label/span[1]/span/input"))).click()
```

This finds the element but doesn't click it.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213417/select-checkbox-using-selenium-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name=confirmWeight]")))

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name=confirmWeight]")
element.click()
```

Explanation:

1. First you need to wait till your element is clickable. For this you have to define the locator which is unique.
2. Find the element and click it

If you want to make an input use:

```
element.send_keys("`your input")
```

If you want to click on svg, that is a child use: `input[name=confirmWeight]>svg`
I don't see it in your html. It looks like the info you provided is not enough.

Comment: Please accept&upvote if the answer is helpful.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. The thing I'm trying to click isn't a button its an input.

Comment: Are you trying to make a text input to your field?

Comment: No, on the page it is clickable with my mouse. When I use inspect and hover over it the <class> is input and svg. There's no <button> or <td>. Very confused.

Comment: Did you try my selector?

Comment: You can use `.jss1805` as CSS selector, but I suspect it is dynamic.

Comment: /html/body/div[1]/div/main/form/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/label/span[1]/span/input
First checkbox^

/html/body/div[1]/div/main/form/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/label/span[1]/span/input
Second checkbox^

Comment: <input class="jss1805" name="confirmWeight" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="">
1st element^

<input class="jss1805" name="confirmTerms" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="">
2nd^ element

Comment: Please update your question. I do not understand where is the problem from your comments.

Comment: I'm trying to use .click() to click on a box. The box is labelled as an input. I try to click the box with .click() and using the full xpath but it doesn't click it. It's able to find it using the xpath but doesn't click it.

Comment: Check out here how to wait for an element to become clickable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66926485/staleelementreferenceexception-selenium-python/66926935#66926935

Comment: Also it is included to my answer to you

Comment: wait for the page to load

Comment: my code uses the wait for it to become clickable module